# How to log clients' HPKP errors in Apache?

Tags: logging

Is it possible to log clients' HPKP errors in Apache? It would seem this would be logged in in the `error_log` or `ssl_request_log`, but even when I set `LogLevel debug`, I don't see anything regarding pinning errors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`report-uri`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7469#section-3):

Use this in Apache:

```
Header always set Public-Key-Pins "report-uri=\"http://example.site/pkp-report.pl\" pin-sha256=\"<EXAMPLEPIN>\";  max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains"
```

where the Perl script simply redirects the POST data to a log file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;

open(my $outfh, ">>", "report-uri.txt") || die "can't open log file: $!";

while (<>) {
   print $outfh $_;
}

close($outfh);

print header();
```

For HPKP, `http://example.site/pkp-report.pl` must be different from the HTTPS site that uses HPKP. For CSP reporting, it can be the same.